# Problema para borrar registro con ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

necesito ayuda porque no me funciona borrar un registro de una tabla en mysql con ajax aqui les dejo el codigo de la tabla

```
<table id="reporte" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <caption style="display: none;">Consulta de Entrada de Productos</caption>

            <thead>
              <tr>                                            
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Fecha </th>
                <th>Receptor </th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Remito</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <?php
              while($arreglo2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='min-width:40px;'>$arreglo2[0]</td>";
                echo "<td>$arreglo2[1]</td>";
                echo "<td style='min-width:60px;'>$arreglo2[2]</td>";
                echo "<td style='max-width:40px;'>$arreglo2[3]</td>";
                echo "<td style='max-width:10px;'>$arreglo2[4]</td>";
                echo "<td style='max-width:10px;'>$arreglo2[5]</td>";
                echo "<td style='max-width:10px;'>$arreglo2[6]</td>";

                echo "<td class='text-center'><span ><a href='#' onclick='eliminar(<?php echo $arreglo2[0] ?>)'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a></span></td>"; 


              }
              mysqli_close($conn);
              mysqli_free_result($resultados);

              ?>

             </tbody>


   </table>
```

// esto es de la pagina donde se deberia ejecutar deletent.php

```
<?php



error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);

require_once("../data/conexion.php");
$id = $_POST['id'];



$productonuevo=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM entradas where entradas.id_entrada = '$id' ");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($productonuevo)) {

      $nuevoid = $row['id_producto'];
      $cantidad1= $row['cantidad_ent'];


    }


  /* borrar entrada */

$delete2="DELETE  FROM entradas  WHERE  entradas.id_entrada = '$id' LIMIT 1 ";

$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $delete2);



$updatepro="UPDATE productos set stock_actual = stock_actual - '$cantidad1'  WHERE  productos.id_producto = '$nuevoid' ";

$result5 = mysqli_query($conn, $updatepro);



?>
```

// a continuación adjunto el script

```
    <script>
  function eliminar(id){

    var id = id;
    $.ajax({

      type:'POST',
      url:"ajax/deletent.php",
      data:"id="+id,
      success: function(data){
       viewData(data);      
      }

    });


  }



</script>
```

Comment: Nadie puede ayudarte si no escribes el código del archivo deletent.php

Comment: Perdon tengo que editar la pregunta para agregar el codigo ??

Comment: Así es, en la parte inferior de tu pregutna hay un botón para editar.

Comment: Lo intento pero no aparece el codigo php de la pagina

Comment: @Julio basta con que elijas todo el fragmento de código que deseas formatear y des a la combinación de teclas `Ctrl` + `K`

Comment: Ok gracias...creo que quedo editado

Comment: No entiendo porqué en data: le pasas "id=" y luego la ID, si en la consulta solo necesitas el ID.

Comment: pero no tengo que pasar el valor de la variable?

Comment: La variable con los datos cuando usas Ajax, tienes que pasarla así: `data: {id: id},` o sea, entre `{  }` allí dentro debes poner los diferentes valores, con un identificador (a la izquierda)  y el dato (a la derecha). Mira la sección `Examples` de la [documentación](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Debes verificar, claro está, que el valor se está recogiendo correctamente en la variable `id`, puedes hacer un  `cosole.log(id);` o algo así, o construir la variable aparte: `mData= {id: id};` probarla con `console.log(mData);` y usarla en el párametro `data` de Ajax, poniendo: `data: mData,`

Comment: Otra cosa, si `id` es una columna numérica en la base de datos, no uses comillas simples, la consulta debería quedar así: `SELECT * FROM entradas where entradas.id_entrada = $id`, los valores numéricos cuando se usan como criterio se escriben sin comillas simples. A veces el DBMS te deja pasar la consulta pero a veces no, por lo que eso puede ser motivo de error aunque recojas el dato correctamente. Si te sigue sin funcionar prueba lo que hay en el POST con un  `var_dump($_POST);` Conviene que completes tu petición Ajax, poniéndole también el parámetro `method: "POST",`

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano soy nuevo en ajax y me cuesta entender los valores me funciono lo que me indico Fernando Urban, me borra el registro aun cuando no he tocado la otra parte del codigo pero no me recarga la pagina cuando ya se realizó la funcion ...es en success verdad ?

Comment: **Ajax es precisamente para no tener que recargar la página**. Puedes usar la información que te traiga Ajax desde el servidor para actualizar el contenido de la página sin tener que recargarla. Eso como bien dices tienes que hacerlo en el `success` o en la función que llamas posteriormente. Pero Ajax es asíncrono, debes saber cómo manejar adecuadamente el parámetro `data` que recibes en el `success`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la línea:

```
echo "<td class='text-center'><span ><a href='#' onclick='eliminar(<?php echo $arreglo2[0] ?>)'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a></span></td>";
```

Si ya estás concatenando PHP dentro de tu `echo` ya no es necesario abrir etiquetas `php`, más bien necesitas concatenar de la siguiente manera la variable:

```
echo "<td class='text-center'><span ><a href='#' onclick='eliminar(".$arreglo2[0].")'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a></span></td>";
```

Comment: Excelente,  borra el registro pero no me recarga la tabla sera en el success

Comment: Gracias Fernando ...solo me queda recargar la pagina cuando ya se cumplio la sentencia sql.  No se como se indica

Comment: Te recomiendo entonces cargar todo por ajax desde un inicio. También lo que puedes hacer es mandar a llamar el mismo archivo que crea tu table desde un ajax y cargarlo dentro de un div, así cuando termines de hacer tu petición ajax que borra el registro vas a mandar a llamar esa función que te carga de nuevo la tabla que mostraste al principio

Comment: pregunto podria hacer lo siguiente : $("#reporte").html(data) despues del success function(data) donde reporte es el id de la tabla?

Comment: Te recomiendo encerrar todo en un div padre y a ese hacer referencia para que no te cause problemas.

Comment: @Julio no le veo mucho sentido a tu lógica. ¿Es necesario realmente recargar de nuuuuevo la tabla, con los encabezados y demás cosas? Esto se aleja bastante del propósito de Ajax, que es precisamente dejar la página como está, **actualizando solamente lo que interesa**. Tampoco está explicado todo el contexto en la pregunta. Pero imaginemos algo común: varios registros mostrados en una tabla, borras uno de ellos, lo correcto sería, cuando Ajax retorne del servidor con un borrado exitoso, quitar esa fila que se borró, no recargar de nuuuuuevo toda la tabla quitando ese registro. ¿Me explico?

Comment: voy aprobar cerrar la tabla en <div id=reporte>...

Comment: pero es que cuando elimino el registro sigue en el datatable y tengo que recargar la pagina para que no salga ese registro...

Comment: @Julio recargar constantemente la tabla es contradictorio totalmente con el propósito de Ajax, por lo que te expliqué más arriba. Yo no uso `datatable` pero puede hasta que haya formas de ligar el `datatable`a la base de datos, de forma que *escuche*  los cambios en la base de datos y actualice los datos. Esto debe existir, si revisas la documentación (algo como sincronización en tiempo real de Firebase). Y si no existe, en vez de recargarlo todo tiene que haber una forma de quitar el registro que haya sido afectado. Eso tienes que verlo en la doc de `datatable`.

Comment: Ok me fijo en los datatables ....Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas voy a probar a ver que sale...Nuevamente muchas gracias!!!